# Change PS1 in .bashrc so that the following directory path is shown:

Tags: bash, command-line, directory, prompt, windows-subsystem-for-linux

A little background:

I am running `Windows 10`, have installed `git bash`, and created the `.bashrc` file.

Right now in my `.bashrc`, I have the following line:

`PS1='\w\> '`

So suppose I am on my desktop, and there is a folder called `test`. In `git bash`, it would show this:

`~/Desktop/Test\> (enter command here)`

In my `cmd`, it would show:

`C:\Users\John\Desktop\Test> (enter command here)`

I like the `cmd` path that it shows, and was wondering if it is possible to show this path instead of the one `git bash` shows, by modifying the `PS1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That seems not possible with `\w` or `\W` but you can do this:

```
PS1='$PWD> '
```